# Можно ли обновить windows 10, если она установлена рядом с ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, windows-10

Я недавно поставил вторую систему рядом с windows 10 - ubuntu 20.04.
И теперь мне надо обновить windows.
Можно ли это делать? Ничего плохого не произойдет?

Comment: Это смотря как вы ставили. Если на один и тот же диск, то обновление десятки может переписать загрузчик, и как следствие вы не сможете загрузиться в юбунту. А может повезет и этого не случится.

Comment: Может слететь линуксовый загрузчик, но восстановить его через LiveUSB не проблема (инструкций навалом в интернете)

Comment: а есть ещё один вариант - у меня было так - винда отказывалась накатывать обновления, ссылаясь на весьма странные ошибки. Исправив бут на виндовый, все прошло сразу и без заминок. Потом просто вернул загрузчик назад.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да можно обновлять.
Но могут возникнуть некоторые проблемы:

1. Загрузчик Grab слетит, и установится стандартный MBR
2. Во время обновления произойдёт перезагрузка или сбой

Как решить?

1. Установить Live дистрибутив, например Antix (он заточен под восстановление Linux систем), и оттуда восстановить загрузчик.
2. Обычно проблема решается сама собой, после повторного запуска обновление продолжается, и завершается успешно, в крайнем случае придётся прибегнуть к точки восстановления.

Заранее подготовьте накопитель с установленной Live системой.

> СОВЕТ: Используйте разные накопители, если хотите пользоваться 2-я ОС
> одновременно, для Linux системы обычно вполне хватает 120-300Gb,
> найдите для себя более подходящий накопитель и установите туда вторую
> ОС, это значительно снизит риск конфликта 2-х ОС.

Comment: спасибо Вам за ответ!